# Legacy Geocoder Retiring - Alternatives to ESRI World Geocoder

Tags: geocoding

Knowing that ESRI is retiring their legacy geocoding systems, what good alternatives for batch geocoding do you know of?

Comment: I have released my batch geocoding algorith & database as a hosted API and whitelabel, available at geocodeforfree.com, or on github at https://github.com/bwheeler96/Geocode-For-Free

Answer (score 1):

Nominatim from openstreet map provides free geocoding:  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Most country's only up to street level.

Cloudemade has a commercial solution.
http://cloudmade.com/products/geocoding

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for something that would port directly into ArcGIS...ideas??

Comment: with a python script you can call and use nomimatin (using json and urllib2: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) otherwise just buy arcgis online geocoding